# IFRAME has a lot of problems with iPad safari

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, iframe, ipad

i am developing a java web application which will be browsed using iPad safari through 3G\VPN connection, i have an IFRAME its SRC is a url to a servlet that sends a pdf file to the IFRAM

```
<iframe src="documentviewer?docid=#{viewIncomingBean.incoming.id}" width="610px" height="5000px"></iframe>
```

problems with IFRAM on iPad Safari are:

1 -after calculating the time taken on server side to flush the pdf file in the output stream to the client i found that the IFRAME takes a very long time to getting rendered and the pdf file loaded on client side (please have a look [Using Iframes Sparingly](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/)).

2 - on iPad Safari the IFRAME can't be scrolled using regular one finger touch style, you must use two fingers to scroll the IFRAME up and down (please have a look [ipad and iframe problem](http://www.lemon8.nl/ipads-and-iframe-scrolling/)).

is there is any other better way to load the pdf file in a web page ????

Comment: Forcing the document to download and open in the native PDF viewer is not an option?

Comment: its not an option,the pdf must be viewed in a specific section (position and size) in the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to develop a pdf viewer for an ipad site we were working on. We could not make the scroll work with other thing but the two fingers.

What we did was to use http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js

it is a javascript renderer for pdf documents. It works great ... of course, if you dont use IE.

another solution is to use the document reader of google ... https://docs.google.com/viewer